# Bxslider Ticker image spacing as a Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, spacing, bxslider, ticker

I installed the BxSlider as a plugin for Wordpress and inserted the php script code to show above the footer on all pages.

The images scroll perfectly across the page except I'm trying to reduce the spacing between the images to show more than one image per transition.

To best explain the website shows as follows http://www.harvestoffalyfoodfestival.com/

How and where can I edit the html/css code to make these adjustments.
The slider settings within the plugin 'Slider Margin' doesn't have any effect when entering your option amount? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a width on the bxslider container, as at the moment it's 100%.

Ideally we need to see more code, as this could also be a settings issue within bxslider.

Have you got your js settings for bxslider?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. No I don't have the code as the plugin needs to be edited within Wordpress. Not sure what bxslider file needs to be edit or where the margin settings can be found. Was wondering if a rule could be created within the plugins CSS file to manipulate the required margin settings?

Comment: let me know if the above helps